# Read embedded resource inside UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

Sorry if the title is bad, really couldn't think of a more concrete way of saying it. But anyway, my problem is as follows:

I have a library I'm writing (`.NET 3.5`), it contains mostly plain code and doesn't use any fancy libraries. The library have one embedded resource (text) file that I want to access.

Is there some way to get this embedded resource without "going through" System.Reflection.Assembly if I'm already "in" the Assembly? As this doesn't work with UWP apps (because the lack of System.Reflection.Assembly)? And since I'm stuck with .NET 3.5 I don't have the `GetTypeInfo()`.

Thanks (and sorry if this is a very weird question)!

Comment: I am not familiar with UWP, but the `Assembly` class itself is already in `System.Reflection` so I am confused by the _get hold of an Assembly reference without using System.Reflection_.

Comment: Yah I understand the confusion, sorry! What it really should say (I will edit), is that I simply want to read the embedded resource without accessing the System.Reflection.Assembly (since I don't have access to that namespace)